# Locally Lipschitz continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Please suggest one reference if it is true.\

Let $f:A\cup B\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a function. Suppose that $f$ is locally Lipschitz on $A$ and $B$ and is continuous on $\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}.$ Then does $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous on $A\cup B\cup(\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}).$

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: A and B are bounded open subsets of $R^{n}$

Comment: A and B are bounded open subset of $R^{n}$

Comment: You should write $f:((A\cup B)\cup (\bar A\cap \bar B))\to \Bbb R.$

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are open it's trivial. Did you mean to ask whether $f$ is locally Lipschitz on $(A\cup B)\cup (\bar A\cap \bar B)$ ?

Comment: Then say what $A,B$ are in the question! Why should we be guessing at what you mean?

Comment: Yes we have to prove that f is locally Lipschitz on (A\cup B)\cup(\bar{A}\cap\bar{B})